# Java StyledDocument: How can I ensure that what the user types never appears already styled?

Tags: java, swing

The user types some text. When they press a button, what they have typed is split up and colour coded:

```
colors.setCharacterAttributes(characters, tokens[x].length(), formatBlue, true);
```

Using a set of rules.

---

When they make an edit between the position as defined by `characters` and the position `characters` + `tokens[x].length()` it comes up in my `formatBlue` style.

However, I would like it to be in black until the user next presses the 'colour code' button I have.

In short: the desired effect is that everything that is typed should always in black, until it has been phrased and coloured differently by the program.

---

So far, the best solution I have is to detect when the caret changes position, and then do:

```
setLogicalStyle(textArea.getCaretPosition(), formatBlack)
```

---

Any better suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the desired effect is that everything that is typed should always in black

You could try using a DocumentFilter. If the text about to be inserted does not contain an attribute then you assign the default black attribute.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get EditorKit from your JEditorPane. It's StyledEditorKit instance. So you can get InputAtributes from the kit and remove all the attributes. Thus all the typing will use the empty AttributeSet.